# How to block flooding traffic to Nginx?

Tags: linux, php, nginx

I have this simple Nginx configuration:

```
server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.error.log;

     root   /var/www/example.com/;

    location / {        
        index index.html index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {        
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/example.com/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

it is the time to prevent flooding(dos) attacks. I would like to implement those two rules:

1) I would block more then 3 requests per second for **PHP requests**.

example:

```
www.example.com/page.php
www.example.com/page.php
www.example.com/page.php
www.example.com/page.php (blocks it stop if it is within the second)
```

2) I would block more then 3 request per second for the same resource

```
www.example.com/img.jpg
www.example.com/img.jpg
www.example.com/img.jpg
www.example.com/img.jpg (blocks it stop if it is within the second)
```

My goal is to completly blocks the requests, I say that because i saw **nodelay** param returns 503 to attackers. In this case if the limit is reached I surelly know that it's an attack, so I want to block the response. With "block" I mean that I do not want to send 503 message, I want that NGINX drops the connections without sending nothing.

How can I optimize this configuration to implement these rules?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

nginx has the [HttpLimitReqModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule) module available. You can define different zones and allowed access patterns. If a user exceeds the allowed number of accesses, 503 is returned.

Comment: as I told above, I do not want to send a message back, I want to drop the connection because it is surelly an attacker. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Apparently nginx can use a special HTTP header as an response where it will silently drop the connection. See [this stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570489/is-there-anyway-to-make-a-rails-rack-application-tell-the-web-server-to-drop-t)

Comment: thank you... but in that example there is a location like /something. Here I need to return 444 if the limit req is reached, does this module accept any other parament to sent a "location"? if it is possible i can put 444 there.